# items components in nativescript not populating the response from django api

Tags: django, typescript, nativescript

I have simple django api which provide a list of movies title with their ids.

I have created a movies service in type script which performs the get operation and get the list of movies title and id.

In native script I have two files, items.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MovieService } from "../services/movie.service";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-items",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./items.component.html",
    providers: [MovieService]
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    items;

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
            movies => {
                this.items = movies;
                console.log(movies);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

and items.component.html

```
<ActionBar title="Movie Rater App" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout class="page">

    <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.title"
                class="list-group-item"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

I am getting blank screen on the app in the emulator - just the action bar title. No exception in logs

I validated API is running fine and even I can see the response in console (i.e. output of console.log(movies)).

Any help will be appreciated.

django API response:

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Rocky (1976)",
            "description": "A small-time boxer gets a supremely rare chance to fight a heavy-weight champion in a bout in which he strives to go the distance for his self-respect.",
            "moviePoster": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pic_folder/rocky-1976-poster2451370.jpg",
            "avg_rating": 5,
            "no_of_ratings": 1,
            "maxRatings": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "title": "Rocky II",
            "description": "Rocky II",
            "moviePoster": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pic_folder/rocky2.jpg",
            "avg_rating": 5,
            "no_of_ratings": 1,
            "maxRatings": 5
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assign the result array to `items` so it suppose to be,

```
this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
        movies => {
            this.items = movies.results;
            console.log(movies);
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    );
```

Also you may not need the `StackLayout` wrapping the `ListView`, you could remove that.